# How to stream CloudFront logs to CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a question about streaming CloudFront logs to CloudWatch. I know that it is possible to save CloudFront logs to S3 bucket and later, I can use lambda function which can be triggered by S3 to send logs to CloudWatch. There is also a possibility to look at streamed logs using Amazon Kinesis Data Streams. However I want to know that if some CloudFront configurations exist to send the logs to CloudWatch. Helpful answers are appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify the issue? There is plenty of info how to enable CW Logs for APi gateway, such as  [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cloudwatch-logs/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it is not what I am searching for. I want to look at cloudfront logs in CloudWatch Logs. How I can configure it? I know one way that cloudfront saves logs to s3 bucket and from s3 bucket I can get logs to CloudWatch using lambda function. But is there any alternative?